# Use fragments or activities inside a tab navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an app with 4 main tab fragments. However, inside each tab, the user can do different actions which brings him to navigate inside that same tab. Should I launch new activities or just replace the tab fragment with new fragments? The big downside I see of using new activities is I lose the tab navigation view.

What should I do? Use only fragments? That's a lot of fragments for one activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use fragments. They fit your situation perfectly. And don't worry, 4 fragments inside one activity is not too much. Fragments are designed to be lightweight, so you can use even more.

Comment: Thanks. But then why do activities even exist? Everyone could just use one application activity and use interchanging fragments.

Comment: @omegatai Fragments appeared only in Android 3.0 :) Activities were there since the beginning of times. Besides that, Fragments cannot replace Activities in every use case.